# JavaScript Regex Problem

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

**Csharp Regex Pattern:**

```
Regex rg = new Regex("(?i)(?<=>)[^<]+(?=</TD>)");
```

**JavaScript Regex Pattern:**

```
var pattern = (?i)(?<=>)[^<]+(?=</TD>);

var result = str.match(pattern);
```

**Csharp Regex pattern work, but javascript regex pattern not work pls help ?**

Comment: You should accept an answer to your previous questions.

Comment: You are trying to parse HTML with regular expressions. Please do not do this, it is wrong, dangerous and completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Alsciende pls help your code not work

Comment: Removed my blatantly wrong answer. [comment by Tomalak:] There are neither look-behinds nor inline modifiers in JavaScript regular expressions. Please explain more closely what you are trying to do. Where does the string come from? What values are you interested in?

Comment: JavaScript don't have look behind lookup.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an HTML fragment in form of a string and are in a browser, trying to consume it with JavaScript:

```
var str = "<TD>33,7</TD><TD>100</TD><TD>20,0</TD>";

var temp = document.createElement("tr");
temp.innerHTML = str;

var tds = temp.getElementsByTagName("td")
for (var i=0; i<tds.length; i++) {
  alert(tds[i].textContent);  // use .innerText in Internet Explorer
}
```

See? No regular expressions necessary - the browser has a perfectly capable HTML parser built-in, no need to make your own. When using a JavaScript framework like jQuery, the above gets even easier:

```
$("<TD>33,7</TD><TD>100</TD><TD>20,0</TD>").find("td").each( function() {
  alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There aren't lookbehinds, or inline modifiers in JavaScript RE.  So we move the `(?i)` to the end of the regexp: `//i`.  The lookbehind is a bit harder to mimic, so its easier to just accept the fact that it can't be done and instead use a capture group to find what you need:

```
var pattern = />([^<]+)<\/TD>/i;
var result = str.match(pattern);

// the match you want is in result[1]
```

**EDIT:** Seems to work fine on both strings you provided:

```
"<td class='asd'>sd</td>".match(/>([^<]+)<\/TD>/i)
// [">sd</td>", "sd"]
```

If you want to match multiple items in the same string you can <strike>ab</strike>use the `replace()` method something like this:

```
var textInTds = []; // empty array we will fill up:
"<td>bla1</td><td class='asd'>sd</td>".replace(/>([^<]+)<\/TD>/ig, function($0, $1) {
  textInTds.push($1); // push onto the array
  return $0; // return the original text so that it doesn't destroy the string
});

// textInTds -> ["bla1", "sd"]
```

Comment: pls <td>bla1</td> work but other 'td' <td class='asd'>sd</td> not work other td

Comment: @oraclee: Boy… you sure do have the wrong attitude. How about commenting on the actual solutions you got and answering the questions you have been asked instead of sprinkling "does not work" and "pls help" comments all over the place.